# PHP Update issue with MYSQL Table, some fields revert to zero

Tags: php, mysql

I have a curious problem, I have the following UPDATE query which works well for me, however when I update column ZW, row 6; column GK row 1 and column OK row 1 they all revert back to zero on update?? All the other fields update perfectly.
MYSQL all set to INT.

```
id = $_POST['id'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
$nachname = $_POST['nachname'];
$Adress = $_POST['Adress'];
$plz = $_POST['plz'];
$ort = $_POST['ort'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$ringe = $_POST['ringe'];
$mzs = $_POST['mzs'];
$mg = $_POST['mg'];

$onezw = $_POST['onezw'];
$twozw = $_POST['twozw'];
$threezw = $_POST['threezw'];
$fourzw = $_POST['fourzw'];
$fivezw = $_POST['fivezw'];
$sixzw = $_POST['sixzw'];

$onegk = $_POST['onegk'];
$twogk = $_POST['twogk'];
$threegk = $_POST['threegk'];
$fourgk = $_POST['fourgk'];
$fivegk = $_POST['fivegk'];
$sixgk = $_POST['sixgk'];

$onegk = $_POST['oneok'];
$twook = $_POST['twook'];
$threeok = $_POST['threeok'];
$fourok = $_POST['fourok'];
$fiveok = $_POST['fiveok'];
$sixok = $_POST['sixok'];

$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET minzw = LEAST(onezw,twozw,threezw,fourzw,fivezw,sixzw), mingk = LEAST(onegk,twogk,threegk,fourgk,fivegk,sixgk), minok = LEAST(oneok,twook,threeok,fourok,fiveok,sixok), date='$date', vorname='$vorname', nachname='$nachname', Adress='$Adress', plz='$plz', ort='$ort', age='$age', ringe='$ringe', mzs='$mzs', mg='$mg', onezw='$onezw', twozw='$twozw', threezw='$threezw', fourzw='$fourzw', fivezw='$fivezw', sixzw='$sixzw', onegk='$onegk', twogk='$twogk', threegk='$threegk', fourgk='$fourgk', fivegk='$fivegk', sixgk='$sixgk', oneok='$oneok', twook='$twook', threeok='$threeok', fourok='$fourok', fiveok='$fiveok', sixok='$sixok' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: Are you getting all values in `$_POST`?

Comment: Normalization anyone?

Comment: Yes the values are being posted for all the fields, only except for the ZW6, GK1 and OK1